# Unable to connect to Oracle DB from docker rootless

Tags: database, oracle, docker, rootless

I've created a docker image to allow users to create containers that encapsulate all of the required libraries to connect seamlessly to our oracle database. Everything works fine except when I switch to docker rootless, then, whenever I try to establish a connection to the DB, I get the error message:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I've tried to connect using `SQLAlchemy`, the `sqlplus` (`sqlplus <my_schema>/<my_passwd>@<db_host>:1521`) executable provided by Oracle and both give me the same ORA-12154 error. What is weird is that I can actually ping the database and resolve its hostname using `dig`. I also tried replacing the DB hostname with its IP address but, again, no success.
On the other hand, connecting to a MySQL DB using the same container works just fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any useful information in the logs.
Here's the Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM <my_own_registry>/oracledb-instantclient:12.2.0.1 AS oracle_instantlcient
FROM python:3.6

COPY --from=oracle_instantlcient /usr/lib/oracle /usr/lib/oracle
COPY --from=oracle_instantlcient /usr/share/oracle /usr/share/oracle
COPY --from=oracle_instantlcient /usr/include/oracle /usr/include/oracle

ENV ORACLE_HOME        '/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64'
ENV PATH               "$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH    "$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
ENV TNS_ADMIN          "$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin"
ENV NLS_LANG           "FRENCH_SWITZERLAND.UTF8"

# Copy the .ora and other conf files in the TNS_ADMIN directory
RUN mkdir $ORACLE_HOME/network \
          $ORACLE_HOME/network/log \
          $ORACLE_HOME/network/trace \
          $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
COPY ldap.ora $TNS_ADMIN/.
COPY sqlnet.ora $TNS_ADMIN/.

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libaio1 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: You don't appear to be COPYing a `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: Alex has identified one issue.  Some unrelated recommendations are (i) never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client (it can lead to clashes if not done correctly).  (ii) no need to set TNS_ADMIN since you are setting it to the default location

Comment: thank you for the inputs: @Christopher, I'll do the changes you recommend. @Alex, yes this is true, there is no `tnsnames.ora` but, if this is the issue, why does it work with the same image in normal (non-root) docker?

Comment: I don't know - I'd guess root has visibility/readability of a `tnsnames.ora` that has your TNS alias, which either doesn't exist, is in the wrong place, or just isn't readable when running rootless. Not sure if that could be an existing file in your TNS_ADMIN directory - maybe see if the file exists now but isn't world-readable. (And I guess the COPY might fail if so - if it can't overwrite it?)

Comment: Actually there is no `tnsnames.ora` anywhere on the host machine or docker image (`find / -name "tnsnames.ora"`) always returns nothing. This is really puzzling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that solves the issue and I think the problem comes from the interaction with LDAP that is somehow different in rootless mode.

Here's the solution:

in the `sqlnet.ora` file, I replaced the `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(LDAP)` with `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES)` and created a new `tnsnames.ora` that contains the connection details I need:

```
<my_service_name>.<my_defaut_domain>= 
(DESCRIPTION= 
 (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<my_host>)(PORT=1521))
 (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<my_service>)))
```

and this works. However, I still have no idea why the LDAP setup I had previously behaves differently in docker rootless and interfered with my configuration in the first place.

Note that this setup works also with the regular (root) docker configuration.